# Switchable current shunt resistor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

Looking at the reference design given for INA826 in the image below, what would my best options be if i wanted to replace J8 with something allowing me to switch in R19 (sense resistor) from a microcontroller (3.3v GPIO)? I am thinking something like a FET, but my design knowledge on the subject is not strong enough to know how to do this with the lowest possible impact on my current readings?

The final circuit will be used to measure inputs on J9:

Voltage: +/-10V, +/-5V, 0-10V, 0-5V, mV Inputs

Current: +/-25mA, +/-20mA, 0-20mA, 4-20mA, 5-25mA

So the solution should preferably support bipolar loops.

[image: INA826 reference design]

Comment: How much parasitic capacitance from an open circuit MOSFET can you tolerate?

Comment: Good question, i am actually not sure. It is to be used with various industrual 24V, 4-20 mA current loop sensors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop#Process_control_4%E2%80%9320_mA_loops

And in open circuit it is to be used with +/- 10 V sensors, but i don't know if any of that is sensitive to capacitance?

Comment: You need to determine this because MOSFETs have both quite high leakage capacitance and also quite high (microampere range) leakage current. Also is the signal bipolar i.e. can swing pos and neg wrt ground? The TVS implies so.

Comment: Yes, the signal light be bipolar.. Should have mentioned that, as we might be looking at +/- 20 mA signals. Edited orignal post

Comment: That is starting to rule out a conventional MOSFET

Comment: Hmm, i might start to realise why i have only found circuits doing this with the "jumper" approach

Comment: Have you considered XTR300, instead? It's an industrial  current loop 0-20mA & voltage +/-10V conditioner.

Comment: The XTR300 looks more like a driver? i am only interested to sensing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your input is bipolar (bidirectional TVS diode was a hint and confirmation in a comment) a convention MOSFET is ruled out. I would suggest [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/3781/A700000007096969.pdf) type of device from Panasonic: -

[image]

It's got low capacitance and sub 1 Ω on-resistance. There are plenty of other variants (also from Panasonic) to be found [in this data sheet](https://www.panasonic-electric-works.com/cps/rde/xbcr/pew_eu_en/ca_semiconductor1154_en.pdf).

Comment: That looks amazing! and just what i am looking for! Though a bit steep pricing, but i guess i can't win every battle!

Comment: You get what you pay for (usually).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a small latching relay. Or a MOSFET.

For minimum effect on the reading you'd want a resistance of much less than 250m\$\Omega\$, which is possible with an N-channel MOSFET connected on the other side of R19 (between R19 and ground). For example, an [AO3400](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3400.pdf) MOSFET has less than about 75m\$\Omega\$ when driven with 3.3V. Off leakage is <5uA at 55°C, which may affect your specification for maximum source impedance in voltage mode.

75m\$\Omega\$ implies an effect of about 0.03% and an effect on the tempco of the combination in the 1ppm/°C range.

Careful PCB layout is required in the current loop.

Your low pass filter elements imply a typical low-frequency process control application, but if you are dealing with an atypical situation then the MOSFET output capacitance of ~75pF might be worth considering.